# SalesForce - The applicationId is not a valid UUID

Tags: salesforce-id, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-android

I have implemented successfully the SF SDK (ver.6.2.2) on a native Android application and everything seems to be working until we decided to generate our release build.

On the debug build we don't have any issues, but on the production one, we have initialisation error "**The applicationId is not a valid UUID**". I have tried everything to make it work, by hardcoding all keys directly into the builder's methods, but the error still can't be fixed.

Here are some facts:

1. The error occurs right after (actually it is inside the execution of this code)
   `MarketingCloudConfig.builder().build(application)`
2. In FireBase we have two projects one for the debug builds and one for the production builds.
3. In SalesForce Dashboard we have also two applications (two projects) , one for the debug builds and one for the production builds. Our SF applications setup is based on the values from FireBase, so stuff like **senderId** and **Server key** are copied from there. (I can see them all correct in the SF dashboard).
4. Our Firebase server keys are applied in  **GCM Client** field in SalesForce Dashboard. (please correct me if this one is wrong)

So far everything looks as it should be, but for the production builds we have this error even thought all keys seem to be correct.

Any help and ideas are appreciated a lot, because this is the last step before production release.

BTW: Our package names for the debug and the production builds are same, it is a long story why (initially they had different suffixes but not now).

- Does the application package name somehow matters when we initialise the SF SDK?
- Is there any connection between SF application id (created by the SF dashboard) and the android application package name?
- Is it possible the same app package name to be associated with more than one SF application id? Kind of having separate SF application id for debug and production builds, where the application package name is aways the same.

Comment: Was a resolution found on this issue ?