# Marketing Cloud SDK android Learningapp not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

First,i want to perform mobile push in marketing cloud.
so i found this Learningapp and i follow through the procedures.
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android

Heres the error what i got in Logcat

```
2020-05-18 11:35:20.671 6104-6104/? I/oud.learningap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-05-18 11:35:20.695 6104-6104/? E/oud.learningap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-05-18 11:35:20.696 6104-6104/? W/oud.learningap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-05-18 11:35:21.450 6104-6140/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp I/DynamiteModule: 
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:13 and remote module 
com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
2020-05-18 11:35:21.450 6104-6140/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp I/DynamiteModule: 
Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2020-05-18 11:35:21.469 6104-6140/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp W/oud.learningap: Unsupported class loader
2020-05-18 11:35:21.510 6104-6104/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-05-18 11:35:21.551 6104-6104/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-18 11:35:21.553 6104-6104/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL     EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp, PID: 6104
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp.LearningApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The applicationId is not a valid UUID.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6465)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The applicationId is not a valid UUID.
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudConfig$Builder.build(Unknown Source:387)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp.BaseLearningApplication.onCreate(BaseLearningApplication.kt:62)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-05-18 11:35:21.565 6104-6148/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-18 11:35:21.583 6104-6104/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.learningapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6104 SIG: 9
```

Used software : android studio 3.6.5
emulator : Nexus 5X 29API

What can be the cause of this errors in logcat?

similar issue:[SalesForce - The applicationId is not a valid UUID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264372/salesforce-the-applicationid-is-not-a-valid-uuid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a valid `applicationId` during SDK initialization.  For the record, you're going to have to provide a valid `accessToken` too ;). [DOCUMENTATION](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/create-apps/create-apps-overview.html) and [DOCUMENTATION](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html#3--initialize-the-sdk)

Comment: I know the reason of those errors. i've been putting a value inside the braces{} in the gradle.properties.
thanks for help!